# Create and access Lua object in Lua, that is stored in a C++ program

Tags: c++, object, lua

Maybe I am bad at Google Searching, maybe I try to over think things, but if I have this Lua class:

```
--Foo:
Foo = {number = 0}
function Foo.setNumber(newNumber)
    number = newNumber
end
```

If I try to use this class in another .lua file, after the file ends, the object is destroyed. Other tutorials I've seen using Lua ([like here](https://eliasdaler.wordpress.com/2014/11/01/using-lua-with-c-luabridge-part-2-using-scripts-for-object-behaviour/)) assume that the C++ program *already knows about the class* so it is defined like a normal C++ class. In my case however, the point of Lua is so that the C++ program is only a framework that handles drawing and such, so can't have Lua classes that are hard-coded into the program.

So, my question is, how can I define and keep a Lua object, using Lua, but the object isn't destroyed unless I specifically tell it to? I was considering creating a class in C++ that stores a vector/map of Lua objects, then the Lua script can request a object using a exposed function. Unfortunately that sounds very slow because for Lua to execute one function, it needs to receive a copy of the class from C++, call the function of the class, then send it back to C++ for it to overwrite the previous copy.

Here is some code that is modified from [Elias](https://eliasdaler.wordpress.com/2014/07/18/using-lua-with-cpp-luabridge/) [Daler's](https://eliasdaler.wordpress.com/2014/11/01/using-lua-with-c-luabridge-part-2-using-scripts-for-object-behaviour/) tutorials on how I'm running Lua scripts (which are very good IMO):

```
#include <lua.hpp>
#include <LuaBridge.h>

#include <string>

//Example class to expose (I realise it's very similar to Foo):
class Bar
{
    private:
        std::string string;

    public:
        void setString(const std::string& newString) {string = newString;}
}

int main()
{
    //Expose the API:
    lua_State* L = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(L);
    luabridge::getGlobalNamespace(L)
    .beginClass<Bar>("Bar")
        .addConstructor<void(*)(void)>()
        .addFunction("setString", &Foo::setString)
    .endClass();

    //Run the script:
    luaL_dofile(L, "script.lua");
    luaL_openlibs(L);
    lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think it depends on how are you calling lua script from C++.

Comment: @stgatilov What do you mean? Like what libraries I'm using?

Comment: If you run "lua a.lua" and "lua b.lua" from console, then they surely do not share global variables. I assume that you call LUA scripts from C++ code. Then it is necessary to ensure that both scripts are using the same LUA state. That's why I'm asking you to provide more details about how are you running the LUA scripts.

Comment: @stgatilov I've been running Lua scripts by exposing my API using Luabridge, then running all `.lua` files in a certain folder using luabridge as well (I'll put some code in my question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Lua, all the global variables are stored in the global table **_G** (called [*environment*](http://www.lua.org/pil/14.html)). Unless someone modifies it explicitly, it is destroyed only when the [Lua state](http://www.lua.org/pil/24.1.html) is destroyed.

So, you can run the second script with:

```
luaL_dofile(L, "another_script.lua");
```

And it should see the global variables left by the first script, because the script uses the same Lua state as the first one.

Answer (score 1):

Lua manages its own lifetimes through garbage collection.  If it can't see an object is used, it will destroy it.  The trick is to store these objects in a lua table, with the c++ adding and removing them, controlling their life time.

Comment: But all the global variables are stored in a special table, aren't they? I think global variables are destroyed only when the LUA state is destroyed (which is a termination of LUA program).

Comment: @stgatilov So you're telling me that, as long as I keep the Lua State, I'm fine? If so I may have just been overthinking things and not fully understanding the way Lua works

Comment: It depends on the life of the object in lua.  If the object is a global, it survives.  If the object was a local in a lua function, then when that function returns to C++, it will need some other lua existence to avoid being collected.